# Present Modal View in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, modalviewcontroller, instagram, uicollectionview

I want to display a modal view but I have two problems:

1. There is no presentModalViewController in iOS 6 and I have to use presentViewController which is just display my second ViewController like a modal segue not a modal window without full screen option,
2. My second problem is how can I show the modal window from UICollectionViewController. I tried to use presentViewController but it just works with ViewController not CollectionViewController.

The best example of what I want to do is this (Instagram). How they made this modal window? Is it because it's still working with older iOS versions and it's not iOS 6 yet? Or there is another way to display modal window like this from UICollectionViewController?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly what you are trying to achieve is to present one of your `ViewControllers` over  the parent and still see the parent `ViewController` in the background.

**First solution:**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; //self.modalPresentationStyle might do a better job here
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Make sure your `SecondViewController` content is smaller than your current ``ViewController` and that you can see the background color of it in StoryBoard \ xib. The background color will be clear and will create the transparency effect.

**Second Solution:**

Create a Container (iOS 6 and up if you are planning to use the Storyboard IB, lower than that will let you create Containers but only progrematicly).

[image: Container]

Set the container size 3/4 of the parent size and connect the second viewcontroller to it. Instead of segueing \ pushing to your second viewcontroller you can just

```
myContainer.alpha = 1;
```

to show it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the docs for UIContainerView which is used for displaying a view controller as a child of another view controller in a similar way to a non-fullscreen modal presentation.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that `presentViewController` is only works with `UIViewController` not `UICollectionViewController.`

Then simply import `UIViewController` class in header file of `CollectionViewController` as displayed below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class UIViewController;

@interface MyCVController : UICollectionViewController

@end
```

Comment: yes but this is a layer above the window, how do you achieve this?

Comment: may be view.window.subviews can help