# How to change view without using segue

Tags: view, ios7, segue

I'm developing a game in xcode 5, and after a collision I need to change the view
 (it's a new view, not the previous, nor the rootView).

Is it possible to do this without using segues?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple ways off the top of my head:

You can use UINavigationController to push another view into the user's view, [or you can do a "`presentViewController:`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774887/present-modal-view-in-ios-6).